# Build the 'AND' query in yii 2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Hello I am trying to find out what method/way is used so that I can build an 'AND' query in my code because I suspect that the query I have been using right now uses the 'OR' query see the code below.

I think this is the building the 'OR' query:

```
 ActiveSubject::find()->where(['clientid' => $clientid,
                               'subjectid' => $subjects['subjectid'],]);
```

I have searched around the internet and people have suggested using `andWhere()`

```
ActiveSubject::find()->select(['clientid', 'subjectid'])
                     ->andWhere(['clientid' => $_user,])
                     ->andWhere(['subjectid' => $subjects['subjectid'],]);
```

But still suspect it is still using 'OR' because the output is still getting everything rows with clientid even though there is no related subjectid. Can you help me finding out what the proper method of building a 'WHERE' query in yii 2?

**EDIT 1:**

I was doing this:

```
  <?php if(ActiveSubject::find()->where(['clientid' => $_user,
                         'subjectid' => $subjects['subjectid'],]))://if true? ?>

<!--do this-->

<?php else: ?>

<!--do this-->

<?php endif; ?>
```

But alas it is not doing the `else:` when the query fails.

**EDIT 2**

My goal was the if function on my end, but I thought the reason it was not working was because of the query that it was not fulfilling the boolean but then  it is actually returning an instance of ActiveQuery and I realized I was wrong. So it would make more sense if I make a function that returns a boolean in the ActiveSubject Model.

Comment: You can enable the debug toolbar and inspect the query that was run from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one uses AND and it's the same as the second one. If you are not sure about produced SQL check your debugger output or call something like:

```
echo ActiveSubject::find()
    ->where([
        'clientid'  => $clientid,
        'subjectid' => $subjects['subjectid']
    ])
    ->createCommand()
    ->sql;
```

Comment: I have revised my code see the edit for further reference. It is true that the query is using the 'AND' query. I forgot to include something in the question because I didn't think mattered but I thought it was possible to use the query as a parameter in an if statement. See the code above.

Comment: It makes no sense - the `if` condition there returns instance of ActiveQuery.

Comment: Ah yes I realized it. What if I make a function in the active subject itself that will return a boolean? Because that is my goal for the if function?

Comment: It will make more sense but it has nothing to do with your `AND` question.

Comment: Yeah my goal was the if function on my end, but I thought the reason it was not working was because of the query that it was not fulfilling the boolean but then you said that it is actually returning an instance of ActiveQuery and I realized I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you would like to use AND query.

You can try to debug the query by printing it by using following code.

```
$query = ActiveSubject::find()->where(['clientid' => $clientid,
                               'subjectid' => $subjects['subjectid']]);

var_dump($query->prepare(Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder)->createCommand()->rawSql);
```

And also, you can try following code.

```
ActiveSubject::find()
->andWhere('clientid = :clientid', [':clientid' => $clientid])
->andWhere('subjectid = :subjectid', [':subjectid' => $subjects['subjectid']]);
```

Comment: There is no need to add `'AND'` there. It works the same with just the array.

Comment: I know. And it uses AND. The problem is not with where() but with DB data.